# Multi dimensional array - gain access to item in structure

Tags: php, foreach

How can I gain access to the 'type' item within the following structure?

The following is output from a foreach, in the variable $item (output from `print_r($item);`)

```
Cartthrob_item_product Object ( 
    [core:protected] => Cartthrob_core_ee Object ( 
        [cart] => Cartthrob_cart Object ( 
            [items:protected] => Array ( 
                [3] => Cartthrob_item_product Object ( 
                    [item_options:protected] => Array ( 
                        [type] => product  
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: `$arr->core->cart->items[3]->item_options['type']`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of PHP, and assuming the objects have the appropriate getters, you could do:

```
$item->getCore()->cart->getItems()[3]->getItemOptions()['type'];
```

If they don't have getters, you can only access `Cartthrob_item_product::core`, `Cartthrob_cart::items`, and `Cartthrob_item_product::item_options` from inside the respective classes themselves because they are `protected`.

Another possibility is that the `Cartthrob_item_product` at index 3 is the same object as $item. In that case, assuming the object has the appropriate getter, you'd simply need to do:

```
$item->getItemOptions()['type'];
```